# Can endermen enter your house when you sleep?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Since they can move blocks, imagine that endermen made a hole in your wall so monsters can now get in
 and disturb your sleep.

Could that be possible ?

Comment: That is one creepy title.

Comment: [Metallica - Enter Sandman](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MPJKuygePHk&feature=autoplay&list=PLF3C34175C1A85915&lf=BFp&playnext=3)

Comment: Yes, they gather in large groups around your bed, standing around and just staring at your face. Some whisper dark nothings that become your nightmares. You should be fine as long as you don't open your eyes.

Comment: @Alex What if someone else is coming around and sees them doing that?

Answer (score 49, accepted):

No.

Time does not pass, in the normal sense, while you sleep.  Instead, the game checks to make sure you are "safe" when you go to bed.  If you are, game time "jumps" to dawn.  Crops don't grow, dropped items don't decay, and **monsters don't move**.  The only way you can be woken in the middle of the night is if you weren't safe *when you went to bed*.

Answer (score 3):

No I do not think so. Unless you have  the Somnia mod which I do not think is updated to 1.8 yet. But you should be safe unless you are right next to a enderman

Answer (score -2):

Considering you can't sleep when mobs are in a 1-10 blocks radius of a hostile mob or anything that can attack you, no.

However, there used to be a bug where if you sleeped when there were monsters nearby they could automaticlly teleport in your house and beat the crap out of you.

But overall, no. They can not enter your house in your sleep.

Comment: They didn't teleport in. The "nightmare" mechanic spawns a skeleton beside you when you sleep in an unsafe bed, and there used to be a bug in the code that made it not recognise some doors as closed.

Comment: @seven I believe that the 'nightmare' mechanic has been removed. (I think?)

Comment: @TheUgly Yep, I should have used past tense there. The nightmare mechanic was replaced with a "monsters are too near to sleep now" mechanic. (I liked the nightmare mechanic better, TBH.)

Answer (score -4):

I woke up with an enderman next to my bed once. He had taken apart my shelter. He didn't do anything to me though since I didn't instigate a fight. It was still terrible creepy for that to be the first thing I saw when daylight came in. But that was like once out of hundreds of times. I assumed it was some type of glitch or the game assumed it wasn't a hostile mod.

Comment: Unless the Enderman came in while the screen was fading out towards 'sleep', I highly doubt this. The game doesn't have anything happen while you sleep, the time goes to dawn, the sun moves to the correct position, and the light adjusts accordingly. The only non-atmospheric change is that it moves you next to the bed.

Comment: This can only happen if you have a sleep mod installed that makes the game *not* skip time.