# How to make an Enderman proof mob trap?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What's the best way to protect your house from Enderman stealing your walls?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/30415/whats-the-best-way-to-protect-your-house-from-enderman-stealing-your-walls)

Although I haven't yet had anything serious happen to my mob trap, with 1.8's release I'm worried that an Enderman might spawn inside my trap and move a block to completely destroy the trap's effectiveness or worse, release the mobs out of the trap into my house!

Is there any guaranteed way to prevent this, or do I just have to hope for the best and be prepared to play damage control?

Answer (score 0):

You can try by putting a 3 block high wall made of fence and i think you were meant to do that because notch has also implemented fence gates to ease accessibility in and out.
Build a moat around it as water damages the enderman.

Put lights around your house or blocks(ur trap) that you don't want the enderman to destroy.

Or you can reduce the rate of enderman spawning by placing pig spawners.

Simply you can also make your trap out of blocks that the enderman can't pick up or build it underground.