# Can mobs spawn on slabs?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Endermen are dismantling my mob grinder.

[This question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/30415/whats-the-best-way-to-protect-your-house-from-endermen-stealing-your-walls) has an answer that suggests endermen can't spawn on slabs, so if I cover the whole floor with slabs, I should be fine. Except I read single slabs are considered "transparent" and monsters can only spawn on "opaque". OTOH, double slabs are considered "opaque"... how does that relate to monster spawning?

Comment: For your second question, you should submit a second question. However, endermen and blocks has already been covered [here](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/30069/what-blocks-can-the-enderman-pick-up-and-what-blocks-cant-they-pick-up) and [here](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/30415/whats-the-best-way-to-protect-your-house-from-endermen-stealing-your-walls), so you don't need to. (I've edited out the second question.)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Mobs cannot spawn on normal, right-side-up single slabs (the ones occupying the lower half of the block), as they're considered transparent blocks. They *can* spawn on upside-down single slabs (as of the 1.5 update) and double-slabs (which are full, opaque blocks).

Flooring your grinder with regular half-slabs will prevent *all* mobs from spawning, not just endermen.

Comment: This is incorrect. Upside-down slabs are valid for spawning; this was introduced in the same update that allowed redstone to be placed on upside-down slabs.

Comment: @KevinReid Ah! Yes, my info is out of date. Funnily, the first version I wrote here was correct then! I'll revert to that.

Comment: Flooring the grinder with double slabs will prevent it from being dismantled. Flooring the OUTSIDE of the grinder with right-side-up slabs will force all mobs to spawn inside only.

Answer (score 5):

No, mobs cannot spawn on single slabs. [This wiki article](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Spawning) explains in detail the requirements for any given mob to spawn.

To prevent endermen from making holes in your grinder, make the spawning level only 2 blocks high, or [set mobGriefing to false](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Commands).

Comment: I like to make my grinders/farms 2.5 high (half block on top). Prevent Endermen from spawning, and give those poor buggers a little breathing room. We're already subjecting them to genocide, no need to be *cruel* about it.

Comment: or make the grinder out of stuff that the endermen can't move (cobblestone is enough)

Comment: @ratchetfreak [Endermen can move cobblestone](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/30460/38952)

Comment: @mikeTheLiar [no they can't](http://www.minecraftwiki.net/wiki/Endermen#Moving_blocks)

Comment: @ratchetfreak hmm. Looks like that answer needs to be updated....

Comment: given that it stems from 1.8.1 beta and the [nerf happened not long after that answer](http://www.minecraftwiki.net/wiki/Endermen#History)

Answer (score 0):

If you have a diamond pickaxe, rebuild your Mob grinder 2 blocks high and out of obsidian. (pretty sure enderman cannot move this)

Answer (score -1):

Mobs can spawn on slabs. I played skyblock on hardcore and thought they couldnt spawn on my bridge but no.There was a spider right there and it knocked me out of the world. (btw was playing on java).