# Is there a rule that means mobs spawn on slabs?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

[Can mobs spawn on slabs?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/117422/can-mobs-spawn-on-slabs) says that they can't.

Unfortunately, this is happening to me:

[image: A zombie pigman standing on a half-slab pathway. Logs underneath show that these are definitely bottom slabs.]

He definitely spawned there, there is no way for him to have got there. I have seen it happen on raised half slab paths as well.

Is there a game rule that has been changed by the server admin?

Comment: Aren't those slabs placed upon slabs?  Mobs can spawn there.  It's only a single slab they cant' spawn on, because they can't spawn on the half-block of invisible space above it.

Comment: Before anyone asks, that resource pack is Faithful and the question-asker should not be using that resource pack for screenshots.

Comment: @Peanut actually it's Minecraft HD, and I'm doing nothing wrong by posting a screenshot of it. Next you'll say I cannot make YouTube videos with texture packs...

Comment: On Arqade, you are supposed to not use resource packs in a screenshot.

Comment: @Peanut link me up with meta post?

Answer (score 15):

Mobs will never spawn on slabs. That pigman did not spawn on that slab.

Mobs will spawn on most opaque blocks (in addition to upside-down slabs and stairs) as long as the rest of their spawning conditions are met. They will never spawn on the bottom half slabs. You can check out all of the spawning conditions on the [Minecraft Wiki](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Spawning#Spawn_conditions).

So what happened here? How did that pigman get there?

There are 2 possibilities:

[image: The two paths this pigman may have taken]

Comment: Alternatively, there's an invisible spawner in range somewhere. Seems unlikely.