# Can players spawn on slabs in Minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

I'm making a pretty spawn area for my world and I want to use slabs for the floor, but can players spawn on slabs? I don't want to place slabs in my spawn area if players aren't able to spawn on them.

Someone asked a [similar question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/117422/can-mobs-spawn-on-slabs) regarding mobs spawning on slabs, but what about players? Can players spawn on slabs?

I am just talking about normal single slabs. So basically, are players able to spawn on the following slabs?:

[image: Minecraft slabs]
[image: Minecraft slabs]
[image: Minecraft slabs]
[image: Minecraft slabs]

Comment: I think they can, half slab should only prevent mobs from spawning

Comment: The simplistic answer is definitely "yes", because if your entire world is covered with slabs, you still need to spawn somewhere. But maybe the game first tries to avoid it, I don't know.

Comment: According to this post from 2013, players can spawn on slabs: https://www.minecraftforum.net/forums/minecraft-java-edition/discussion/2443577-can-players-spawn-on-a-half-slab (But this is from 2013. Does someone have concrete evidence that it is possible?)

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: Yes, they can.

Long answer: A lot of players build paths from one place to the other, using slabs, so monsters don't spawn and hit you while running around doing stuff.

If you log out on said slab, you will just log back in on the same tile.

If you're talking about **re**spawning, that is a different story (say you place a bed between a lot of slabs). In this case, after death, you will respawn on your bed instead of the slab.

Comment: I'm talking about respawning, yes. Say someone dies or enters the world for the first time. Will they be able to spawn on slabs?