# Are monsters destroying my walls?

Tags: minecraft-legacy-console

I have created a mud wall around my "estate" about 7-8 blocks high, just to keep monsters from getting too close to my house, especially creepers.

Sometimes when I wake up there can be one block just missing from my wall even though I never had anything trying to attack me the night before.

Is this an enemy damaging my wall or some sort of glitch?

This is Minecraft for the PS4 by the way

Comment: Sounds like an endermen visited you.

Comment: @Arperum ooh, I'm new to the game so I only found out what they are the other day. What do they actually do?

Comment: Monsters?  Destroying *my* walls?  [It's more likely than you think.](http://knowyourmeme.com/memes/x-in-my-y)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, it sounds like an Enderman has come to visit. These creatures spawn in darkness and (amongst other things) will pick up certain blocks and move them around, as described on the [Minecraft Wiki](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Enderman):

> Endermen have a unique ability to pick up certain block types and move them around, which they generally spend their time doing while neutral. They can also step up one full block without having to jump.

In terms of defending your home from Endermen, the answers to [this question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/30415/whats-the-best-way-to-protect-your-house-from-endermen-stealing-your-walls) have some tips you may want to try. Alternatively, you can try building your home (and surrounding wall) out of materials that an Enderman can't move, such as stone or brick (the Wiki article has a full list of blocks that they *can* move.)

Comment: The wiki is offline now, but if you're using mods, will they also pickup mod blocks? and do they pickup those that are part of multiblock structures, like, say, a Yogscast complete pack Reactor? Or does it depend on what the modmaker decided to do with it?

Comment: Endermen use a list of blocks that they won't pick up. If your mod added the mod block to the list, then they'll avoid it. If the mod creator didn't modify the list, then they'll pick it up.

Answer (score 2):

A little addition to what was already said: Another possibility is to cover the wall in water. Endermen will be hurt and flee if they touch it, therefore unable to touch your wall.

Answer (score 1):

The [Enderman](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Enderman) is a semi-passive mob that has a somewhat annoying ability. They will actually pick up and re-place blocks (generally just dirt blocks) as they see fit.