# How to prevent others from changing a structure in Minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-legacy-console

I have constructed several structures in Minecraft but have noticed that when I log back in some of the structures are changed or damaged.

So is there some way to create a user group that will prevent players not in the group from making changes?

Comment: Are you running any plugins on your sever? (I assume you are on a server since you mentioned logging in)

Comment: i log in to my ps3 and start playing. so i guess i log into PSN.

Comment: Wait, so this is a singleplayer world on PS3?

Comment: I have just started on minecraft, so not sure. I have installed the game from PS store. And I started playing/building. How do I find out if it is single player?

Comment: If you are playing Minecraft without entering any servers or IP-addresses, you are indeed playing singleplayer. This means that you are playing on your own without people being able to join your world, therefore can noone destroy your buildings.

Comment: So this is presumably about Endermen?

Comment: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/30415/whats-the-best-way-to-protect-your-house-from-endermen-stealing-your-walls

Answer (score -1):

I have two solutions for you. One tell them to knock it off. Or enable player priveleges. Then uncheck the "can destroy tiles" now they can't mine your home!